# How to add space from hard disk to ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed ubuntu in dual boot. Now I had limited SSD space so I only allotted 50GB of SSD space to ubuntu while installing. Now I have started to run out of space, I would like to allot 100GB from my **Hard Disk** to ubuntu. I will create a partition in hard disk but then how can I allot the free space to ubuntu.


In a nutshell I want my ubuntu to run on both SSD and hard disk just like windows.

Any suggestions will be helpful, I looked at other questions but they only increased the size of the current drive only. I want to add a drive to ubuntu just like D drive in windows.

Comment: Your end-use case will dictate what is best, we have no knowledge of what that is, don't even know if you're asking about a desktop? or server? system for example, nor how you'll use the space.

Comment: A normal system in dual boot

Comment: [This help doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) will walk you through the process 

Comment: Use Windows Disk Management to create space on the disk, then expand Ubuntu into it using GParted.

Comment: You can define a separate partition and mount e.g. `/home` on it (or `/var`, or something else that's big), or enlarge your root partition, possibly moving another partition out of the way first. However, you can only do that while the disk is not mounted, which means booting from e.g. a Live USB system.

Comment: I have ubuntu in dual boot alongside windows, I don't do anything special on it, I will use the space for normal use only, like downloading apps,etc.